# Shibboleth concurrent logins fail

Tags: java, concurrency, shibboleth, idp, multi-factor-authentication

I have deployed a Shibboleth IDP 3.4 with MFA authentication flow. The first flow is the traditional password, the second one a 2FA flow based on External Authentication (a servlet).

Authentication works as expected for one user at a time. However, when multiple users try to login at the **same** time, only the last one is able to login. All other users produce the following error after *successful* authentication in the idp log:

```
2019-09-11 11:19:22,006 - ERROR [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow:78] - Profile Action SelectSubjectCanonicalizationFlow: No potential flows left to choose from, canonicalization will fail
2019-09-11 11:19:22,008 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.SelectAuthenticationFlow:138] - Profile Action SelectAuthenticationFlow: Moving incomplete flow authn/MFA to intermediate set
2019-09-11 11:19:22,008 - INFO [net.shibboleth.idp.authn.impl.SelectAuthenticationFlow:313] - Profile Action SelectAuthenticationFlow: No potential flows left to choose from, authentication failed
```

The 2FA servlet is basically the following approach:

```java
String authenticationKey = ExternalAuthentication.startExternalAuthentication(request);
final ProfileRequestContext profileRequestContext = ExternalAuthentication.getProfileRequestContext(authenticationKey, request);
final SubjectCanonicalizationContext c14nContext = profileRequestContext.getSubcontext(SubjectCanonicalizationContext.class);
if (c14nContext != null && c14nContext.getPrincipalName() != null) {
usernameShib = c14nContext.getPrincipalName();

//do 2FA ...
//if successful:      
  request.setAttribute(ExternalAuthentication.PRINCIPAL_NAME_KEY,usernameShib);
  ExternalAuthentication.finishExternalAuthentication(authenticationKey, request, response);
//if not:
  request.setAttribute(ExternalAuthentication.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR_KEY, AuthnEventIds.AUTHN_EXCEPTION);
  ExternalAuthentication.finishExternalAuthentication(authenticationKey, request, response);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why a **concurrent** authentication fails or can suggest where I should look?

Comment: The logs show activity of the servlet from the first pending login. When the second login starts, I can only see the output of the second one in the log. It seems like the servlet from the fist login just stops?